# Trying to disable submit button when there is zero input

Tags: html, typescript, bootstrap-4

I am just a mere beginner. I am trying to use typescript and html to disable the submit button when a user does not enter in a part number. I am having some issues as I get the error when attempting to do so,

```
 "Cannot find name 'partNumber'".
```

If any advice could be spared it would greatly be appreciated. Here is all the code that pertains to this....

```
<div>
    <button id="submitButton"
        :class="{ disabled:partNumber == -1 }"<--error here-->
        :disabled="partNumber == -1" <--and here-->
        @click="submitItem"
    >
        <span>Submit</span>
        <i class="fas fa-send"></i>
    </button>
</div>
```

Here is the typscript.js

```
 mounted() {
    for (let element of this.partStore.partEntries as PartDefinition[]) {
      if (element.id == parseInt(this.$route.params.id.toString())) {
        this.localPartEntry.partNumber = element.partNumber;
        this.localPartEntry.variant = element.variant;
        this.localPartEntry.revision = element.revision;
        this.localPartEntry.description = element.description;
        this.localPartEntry.supplier = element.supplier;
        this.localPartEntry.previewImagePath = element.previewImagePath;
        this.localPartEntry.previewImageDateTime = element.previewImageDateTime;
        this.localPartEntry.obsolete = element.obsolete;
        this.localPartEntry.internalOnly = element.internalOnly;
        break;
      }
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your script, your `partNumber` is stored in `this.localPartEntry.partNumber`.

So the disable condition should be `:disabled="localPartEntry.partNumber == -1"` instead of `:disabled="partNumber == -1"`.

So the template will be

```
<div>
    <button id="submitButton"
        :class="{ disabled: localPartEntry.partNumber == -1 }""
        :disabled="localPartEntry.partNumber == -1"
        @click="submitItem"
    >
        <span>Submit</span>
        <i class="fas fa-send"></i>
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, I guess I should have added that I did in fact try this and I get this error, "This condition will always return false since the types string and number have no overlap"  I do have part nuumber set as a string, but I do not know what to put to say when the string equals zero

Comment: Also, when I set the localpartentry.partnumber as null, the submit button still is not disabled

Comment: Remove parseInt inside the if condition and check and try

Comment: I tried that, but I think because I have strings numbers and booleans, I need the parseInt because I get another error saying "This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'number | undefined' and 'string' have no overlap.

Comment: Check definition of PartDefinition. Check the type of I'd. Route params will always be string. So check type of I'd and do comparison